# I'm having trouble running Tensorflow-gpu in my Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a GTX 1650 and a Windows 10. I downloaded CUDA 10.1 along with cuDNN v7.6.4 (September 27, 2019), for CUDA 10.1. After following a tutorial I did what I was told on the tutorial.

After I was done I ran a script to check:

`from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib`

`print(device_lib.list_local_devices())`

and I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in
>   load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in
>   load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pypy.py", line 1, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 101, in 
>       from tensorflow_core import *   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core__init__.py",
>   line 40, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util   File
>   "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 50, in **getattr**
>       module = self._load()   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 44, in _load
>       module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in
>   load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\prono\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in
>   load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.

P.S. This is my first time posting a question, Please forgive me if I made the post unclear. I just don't know what more to add

Answer (score -1):

for windows 10:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html

for ubuntu 18.04, check my cuda install manual:

https://gist.github.com/sailfish009/2f542992a67da726f41dcc9692da3f56

--

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

> I had the same issue while trying to use tensorflow-gpu on windows 10.
>   Since i couldn't get it to work on cuDNN10..i opted for 9 instead
>   using...
>
> ```
> conda create --name tf-gpu
> conda install -c aaronzs tensorflow-gpu
> conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
> conda install -c anaconda cudnn
> conda install keras-gpu
> ```
>
> you can also check the fullpost on
>   https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-to-Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-on-Windows-10-Without-Installing-CUDA-1187/
>
> Credit to Dr Donald Kinghorn

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it